# Why are (long) comments posted as answers being flagged as "low quality"?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

After reading a PHP related question (that already had an accepted answer), I wrote up a comment regarding OP's code, with some suggestions. Since the comment ended up way too long, I decided to post it as "answer", while making it as "comment".

A day later that post in was deleted for being "low quality". Which would make one wonder, what are those quality standards, that Perl and JavaScript use.

[Review queue entry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16154749) for the post in question and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoAdd.png) for sub-10k users.

Is there a guideline, that says, that these types of posts have to be deleted?

Comment: It was most likely flagged as "Not An Answer" not "low quality", and it was deleted because it's not an answer.  Considering that you're openly stating that it's not an answer, it being deleted for being, Not An Answer seems pretty...expected.

Comment: How, at 44k rep, do you not know that comments are for comments and answers are for answers?  The comment character limit exists for a reason.

Comment: So yesterday I parked my car in a "no parking zone", and I got a ticket. What gives?

Comment: @Patrice Clearly the tyrannical police force was abusing their power and power tripping at your expense.  You did nothing wrong.

Comment: Meh..  parking enforcement officers are failed PHP developers.

Comment: Well You provided great information and advice to op, I hope he saved all your link. You should repost your link as comment so Op can access them even if the answer is deleted.

Comment: because they are low quality?

Comment: Related: [https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen/status/842418066461995008](https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen/status/842418066461995008)

Answer (score 27):

Even you yourself wrote *"this is not an answer"* on top of something posted as an answer.

I don't see why you are surprised this gets deleted. Answers are for answers only.

Comment: So, if I cant fit a "comment" in one comment, should I post 3 or 4 of them? What if I my "long form comment" contains multiple lines of code with details and explanations? Or should I just let the newbie to rot.

Comment: @tereško While not a perfect response to your question, these two questions are very related: [Answer too commentarial, but too long for comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/2415822), [What is the proper ettiquette if I have a clarification too long for a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319905/2415822)

Comment: First of all, keep in mind that comments are meant for critique on posts or requests for clarification, not for complete codereviews or anything close to that. That said, IMO pointing a user towards further reading is often useful, but you should keep it short. State the issues you see, then show them where to find further information if necessary. That should take at most 2 comments (which I don't think anyone would complain about). If no good explanation for some issue exists, that sounds like grounds for a new Q/A.

Comment: @tereško Without the "this is not an answer" header, your post consists of 928 characters of Markdown, so it would fit comfortably in a pair of comments. The advice in Baum mit Augen's comment is sound; I, for one, do that relatively often.

Comment: @tereško: Giving advice is not wrong. But at the same time, there are quantities of advice where you're detracting from the goal of the site: to create a repository of useful, easily found information. Your information may be useful, but would someone who needed it find that info by searching for that particular question? Probably not. Then the advice is in the wrong place. You're focusing too much on the needs of the OP and not enough on the needs of Stack Overflow. SO is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 16):

The "Answer" section is for *answers* and not comments. If you post a comment as an answer, it stands to reason that it is not meeting the guidelines of *an answer.*

We want to make it easy for people to find the answer to their problems. The separation of Answers and Comments helps greatly with this. If we allow the "Answers" to be filled with comments that do not answer the question, all we're doing is cluttering the answer section and making it harder for people to find the solutions they are after.

As a note, it's quite likely your post was flagged as "Not an Answer" since it was, indeed, *not an answer.* This would have sent it to the Low Quality Review Queue, just as a "Very Low Quality" flag would have.

The "Not an Answer" flag description itself even mentions answers that should have been comments, such as in your case.